# Getting Command line argument issue in python

Tags: python, if-statement, command-line-arguments

I am having an issue. I need to first validate if the python script has at least 2 variables and then check if there is a "-v" option as the first argument. My code keeps throwing an index out of range exception

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    if sys.argv[1]=='-v':
       print('verbose option chosen')
    else:
       print('verbose option not chosen')
else:
    print('not enough variables, try again')
```

Comment: Can you post the command line that cause the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your're checking the wrong way. You want the first part to execute if `sys.argv` has *at least* 2 elements. You want this:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
```

And if you've got some time on your hands, check out the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I typed it the wrong way i had that, but i still get the error on sys.argv[1]=='-v':

Comment: Okay so now that you've edited your question my answer doesn't make any sense. Could you explain what was wrong?

Comment: i had code above with an empty if statement above this, that was not in here. dumb syntax error